# Как активировать скрипт при нажатии левой кнопкой мыши на блок ?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Допустим, у меня есть блок. У него есть свои стили. Я хочу, чтобы при нажатии левой кнопкой мыши на блок он менял фон на черный. Как сделать в js либо jquery?

```css
#first
{
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    background-color: #FA174C;
}
```

```html
    <div id="first"></div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
$(function() {
  // Левая кнопка
  $('#first').click(function() {
    $(this).css('background-color', 'black');
  });
  // Правая кнопка
  $('#first').contextmenu(function() {
    $(this).css('background-color', 'blue');
    return false;
  });
});
```

```css
#first {
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    background-color: #FA174C;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="first"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
document.getElementById("first").onmousedown = function(event) {
    if (event.button == 2) { //if (event.which == 3) {
        alert("right clicked!");
    }
}
```

```css
#first
{
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    background-color: #FA174C;
}
```

```html
<div id="first"></div>
```

`button == 0` — левый клик, `button == 1` — клик на колесико/среднюю кнопку, `button == 2` — правый клик

P.S. Где-то (не помню где) рекомендуется использовать `which`, вместо `button`.

`which == 1` — левый клик, `which == 2` — клик на колесико/среднюю кнопку, `which == 3` — правый клик